# ios android Cross-platform http request api

Tags: android, ios

Right now I use c++ code for logic component so that I can reuse them in both android and ios. I wonder if there is cross-platform http request library too? So that I can share function to call web request and parse json data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want common coding for both platform you may use cross platform language like Kotlin or Xamarin

Comment: by my understanding, Xamarin cannot be exported to other android and ios native project? Will take a look at Kotlin, thanks for the suggestion